# Autowired to type class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I've write this code:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class Config
{
    @Autowired
    private List<CustomEditor<?>> editors;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstructor()
    {
        log.debug("postConstructor: editors={}", editors);
        for (CustomEditor<?> editor : editors)
            PropertyEditorManager.registerEditor(editor.returnedClass(), editor.getClass());
    }
}
```

And

```
public abstract class CustomEditor<T> implements PropertyEditor
{
    protected T value;

    public Class<?> returnedClass()
    {
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

        return (Class<?>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
```

And it perflecty work, but i want to improve my code and I don't want to instanciate my object because registering only ask for class.

Is there anyway to do this with spring ?

Comment: You won't get around instanciating something, but you could extract the configuration to something like a `Tuple<Class<?>, Class<?>>` instead of having it in the editor implementations (which serve a dual purpose in your case).

Comment: yes but i use autowired for automatisation :)

Comment: You would autowire those tuples instead of your custom editors. But that would remove the ugly `returnedClass` method that has no proper reason to exist in `CustomEditor` other than it's required for configuration. (It also breaks you you extend `CustomEditor` twice because the generic parameter is now in the super-super-class)